# Bitdefender not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, antivirus

I installed bitdenfeder using various methods but the antivirus engine's never loaded and whenever I tried to update them Bitdefeder used to close.
I uninstalled it everytime to try a new method but everytime the result was same.
Last time I installed bit defender using

http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-bitdefender-on-ubuntu-14-04-13-10-13-04-12-10-12-04-linux-mint-16-15-14-13-pear-os-8-7-and-elementary-os-0-2/

But the problem has remained.
Please suggest solutions.
Thanks

Comment: I bet when you run it as 'su', it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Fix for Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu 11.04 to 16.04, 64 bit system. Run as root:

```
ln -s /opt/BitDefender-scanner/var/lib/scan/bdcore.so.linux-x86_64 /opt/BitDefender-scanner/var/lib/scan/bdcore.so
rm /opt/BitDefender-scanner/var/lib/scan/bdcore.so
ln -s /opt/BitDefender-scanner/var/lib/scan/bdcore.so.linux-x86_64 /opt/BitDefender-scanner/var/lib/scan/bdcore.so
```

I found this posted at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1870666

Answer (score -1):

I installed it and run as a root in a terminal this command:

```
/opt/BitDefender-scanner/bin/bdgui
```

On my Ubuntu 14.04, it just worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

You may find in
Bitdefender Settings:

- Select *Load Program at Boot startup*
- and *Load Antivirus engine at startup*

I hope this solves your problem.